# How to read email address in text file and send email to those email address using terminal

Tags: shell-script, email

Im a newbie for scripting. Could you guys help me on how to read email address from a text file and send a email to those email address.

For example I have a `emailAdd.txt`

Inside that txt file:

```
abcde@gmail.com
fghijk@gmail.com
lmnop@gmail.com
```

And I want to send “Hello World” to those email. This is just an example, I need to send to around 30 email address.

Comment: Thanks jesse_b. Your way is to send email one by one right? May I know how to send to many, not one by one.

Comment: Thanks jesse_b. Your solution helps me too. I have one more scenario. Can you help me . i too have the same emailAdd.txt and i have a list of attachments. they are abc.pdf, def.pdf, ijk.pdf. i want first email id to recieve abc.pdf, then second email id to receive def.pdf and so on. Could you suggest the code?

Answer (score 2):

```
file=/path/to/emailAdd.txt

while read -r email; do
    printf '%s\n' 'Hello, world!' | mail -s 'This is the email subject' "$email"
done < "$file"
```

This will loop through each line in the txt file and set the `email` variable to the full line (which is only an email address in your example data).  It will the print `Hello, world!` and send that to each email with the subject `This is the email subject`.

See [mail(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mail)

Note emails sent from `mail`/`mailx`/`sendmail` will often be caught by your emails spam filter.

Comment: I think `mail` should add the appropriate headers by itself? Though you may want to override the `From` address if your system doesn't receive mail (`-r` in the two different `mail` utils I checked). And if you do create a file with the headers included, I don't think you can send it just like that with `mail`, the "headers" will just become part of the message

Comment: @ilkkachu: It works for me that way although to be fair I use `mailx`.  I just `cat file | mailx`

Comment: well yeah, I think the important question is "which `mailx`". (I think e.g. Debian has at least three packages that provide an alternative `/usr/bin/mail`) The one I've used doesn't pick headers from the message proper.

Comment: @ilkkachu: `mailx version 5.0` and yea sorry I also use the `-t` option which "scans input for to:, from:, and bcc: fields".  It also works fine to pull the subject line though too so I think it is reading the header.  Although that is not the same version of mail/mailx on my mac.

Comment: Your way is to send email one by one right? May I know how to send to many, not one by one.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what email client you have on the CLI. As far as looping through the emailAdd.txt you can accomplish this with a for loop. You can find how to send CLI emails using five different ways on this website:

https://tecadmin.net/ways-to-send-email-from-linux-command-line/

However here is an example that will do as you've asked:

```
#/bin/bash
file="/path/to/emailAdd.txt"

while read -r line
do
    sendmail $email  < /path/to/email.txt
done < "$file"
```

`email.txt` could be setup as follows:

```
Subject: Hello World

Email Content Hello World
```

Comment: Thank you for that Jesse. I've edited it to correct this problem!

Comment: You did not fix the problem but you have added some new ones.

Comment: I have tested the for loop with an echo command as I don't currently have a mail client setup, it reads each line and echos each line (I used echo as a test)

Comment: See [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/237982) and [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/237982)

Comment: Also [bash pitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29)

Comment: Thank you for the links, I will have a look at them in due course!

Comment: tl:dr That is not how you read a file with the shell, see my answer for a more accepted way of doing it.